# Темизация node в drupal7

Tags: drupal

есть типы материалов таксономии,в представлении в шапку добавлено текстовое поле,которое появляется во всех нодах.

Вопрос,как узнать nid определенной ноды и убрать вывод текстового поля(мне надо чтобы в некоторых нодах не выводилося текстовое поле)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В node.tpl.php существует объект $node. Описание всех переменных видимых в том или ином темплейте в "phpdoc" в шапке файла. Чтобы получить id ноды достаточно написать

```
$current_nid = $node->nid;
```

$current_nid будет присвоен id активной ноды.

Answer (score 2):

Самый легкий способ узнать  nid  - открыть страницу ноды и посмотреть ее исходный код , в теге  body  будет класс с айди (к примеру page-node-288) , а убрать можно в шаблоне ноды.